# How can we get counts of each group when grouped by a certain field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Here is how my doc looks like.

```
{
    "Summary": "The One Way You're Putting Pressure on Your Partner Without Realizing It=20",
    "Industry" : "Lifestyle and Fitness",
    "Name": "Kali Coleman",
    "Email" : "query-bixh@helpareporter.net",
    "Media Outlet": "Best Life Online"
},
{
    "Summary": "The One Way You're Putting Pressure on",
    "Industry" : "High Tech",
    "Name": "John Smith",
    "Email" : "query-tech@helpareporter.net",
    "Media Outlet": "Anonymous"
}
```

I want to count the documents for each type of "Industry" field.
Here is what I want as an output.

```
{
    "key": "Lifestyle and Fitness",
    "count": 1200
},
{
    "key": "High Tech",
    "count": 590
}
```

I found a similar post here [ElasticSearch count multiple fields grouped by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191810/elasticsearch-count-multiple-fields-grouped-by), except that I do not have to filter.
And I tried it on my Kibana console, got the following error.

```
"root_cause" : [
      {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [Industry] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
      }
]
```

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `terms` aggregation just like in the example **and** you can do so w/o a filter. Once you've configured your `Industry` field's mapping to be [of type `keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#before-enabling-fielddata), you can then run

```json
GET index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_industry": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Industry.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The code worked as expected.
Can you please explain what difference it brings inside the box by changing it from "Industry" to "Industry.keyword"? Wanted to know how it works in elasticsearch. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. There are many articles written about this but to put it very bluntly, `text` is for partial searches and `keyword` for exact matches. Now, in order for ES to do that, this text must be analyzed which consequently increases disk space etc. Plus, aggregating (exact terms) on such text fields is [very expensive too](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#before-enabling-fielddata). So what's done instead is enabling the `keyword` field type which takes the values as they are, i.e. exact terms with capitalization, whitespace, etc. all preserved.

Comment: Shameless plug: I'm writing an Elasticsearch handbook. [What else would you like to learn about](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV)?